# How can I center text on an image using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my website there is a "What we offer" section. I placed three images with text in this section. I want the text and the green background to be centered on the images on all devices. I used the following code, but it's not working.

**Bootstrap HTML code:**

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <h1>What we offer</h1>
    <hr class="separator">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="we-offer">
            <img src="images/multiple-food_01.png" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block">
            <h3>Cooking Classes</h3>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**My custom CSS code:**

```
.we-offer h3 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top:30%;
   text-align: center;   
   left: 0;
   right: 0;   
   border-top: 1px solid #fff; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
   border-right: 1px solid #fff; 
   padding: 10px;   
   color:#fff;
   background-color: rgb(162, 173, 0);    
   background-color: rgba(162, 173, 0, 0.5);    
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

**What it looks like now:** 
[image]
Can you show me how can I center the `Cooking Classes` text with  `green background box` on the image to all device ?

**More or less what I want:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abxw5ade/2)

The `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` is what's going to give you ultimate centering.

You have a default `margin-top: 20px` on there that needs to be zero'd out. Also remove the `left:0;` and change all CSS to below:

```
.we-offer h3 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top:50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   white-space:nowrap;
   text-align: center;   
   margin: 0;
   border-top: 1px solid #fff; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
   border-right: 1px solid #fff; 
   padding: 10px;   
   color:#fff;
   background-color: rgb(162, 173, 0);    
   background-color: rgba(162, 173, 0, 0.5);    
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

**Please note you need CSS3 capability to do this.**

Comment: Well, let me check it.

Comment: Also did you want the `border-right: 1px solid #fff` on there? Doesn't make sense to have it.

Comment: border is just for design. But now its center the text but not the green background. I want to center the text with green background on the image.

Comment: the `<h3>` has the green background, so that's kind of impossible that it's not centered in it's own background color. If you could provide a picture of what you're doing that'd help

Comment: Just need to remove the `width:100%` and optionally add a `white-space:nowrap`